# javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode() Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, oc4j

I have persistence-api-1.0.2,hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final and other related jars in the lib directory. However, when I am deploying war file, I am getting the following error

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()
Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Update

Jars in lib folder

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you have JPA API 1.0 (which is what persistence-api-1.0.2 is) and JPA API 2.0 (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api) in the CLASSPATH at the same time??
Decide which version of JPA you are using before you do anything else

Comment: I have removed persistence-api-1.0.2, still I am getting the same error. I have added list of related jars in my question. Thanks

Comment: deploying your app where? app server? most app servers include a version of JPA by default, so adding another one will likely still find the default also

Comment: I am trying to deploy to Oracle Application Server 10.1.3.5 OC4J

Comment: so look at what jars that appserver includes itself, and search its docs for how to swap out its ancient version of JPA (1.0)